# Why meteor database(mongo db) contents is not uploaded in the github repo?

Tags: mongodb, git, github, meteor

I uploaded a meteor project on github repository. Once I finished uploading, I downloaded the zip file to check if it is functioning properly. The project runs, however, there is not even a single collection in mongodb. (Note my meteor version is 1.8)

Can someone please help me get why the database collections are not stored/uploaded in the github repo and how can they be stored on github repo?

Comment: Your database certainly _shouldn't_ be uploaded to GitHub. Data isn't code. With a regular database it would be common to include database _migrations_ with your code, but not data. I'm not sure if that concept transfers to MongoDB or not.

Comment: Also, it's important to realize that `git push` doesn't operate on _files_. It operates on _commits_. Anything you haven't committed won't get pushed anywhere. (Again, for data in your database, that's a Good Thing.)

Comment: When I compress my project folder to .zip file and upload it on google drive, that database is attached there. Same is not in the case of github.

Comment: I don't know how MongoDB stores its data, but that surprises me. In any case the point is that it _should't be_. Data doesn't belong in your repository. If it's literally stored in files in your directory the technical answer is probably that it's being ignored by your `.gitignore`, but I _**very strongly** urge you not to change that_. Tracking data will cause real problems and give you all sorts of headaches.

Comment: Okay Thanks. :) @Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the designed behaviour of classic 3 tier web apps architecture. Your app code is separated from your app data.

Technically, the MongoDB data of your Meteor project in dev mode (i.e. when you start it with `meteor run`) is in your Meteor project `.meteor/local` folder, which is correctly excluded from version control by `.gitignore`.

Note that in production (i.e. when you use your app after doing `meteor build`) you will have to provide a `MONGO_URL` environment variable to specify where your MongoDB can be reached, since your local dev data will not be shipped with the built app.

Now you can backup your data (e.g. mongodump) and use the dump to fill up your new MongoDB. You can also do it automatically, typically in your Meteor server startup, if you find empty collections.

Comment: Can you please provide further assistance on how can this be achieved during meteor server startup? @ghybs

Comment: There are many ways, each with some drawbacks. Since you seem in need of detailed help, it would probably be more appropriate to open a new question with details of your specific needs and how you are trying to do it.

Comment: Looking for advice might be considered off topic for SO, so feel free to ask on the Meteor forums as well and the folks over there can help you step by step.